# Are Muslim men allowed to see naked breasts of slave woman when they purchase them?

Tags: fiqh, slavery

Are Muslim men allowed to see naked breasts of slave woman when they purchase them?

Answer (score -1):

This is not permissible except what is mentioned in the narration of Ibn Umar he went around and lifted the cloth to check the slave girl's legs and placed his hand between his buttocks and breasts.

Slaver Girls' Awrah still is to be covered until she is solely owned by the master.

Answer (score -4):

No they are allowed to do that.